# Can't be get any notification when the friend request one user to another user through nodejs in android Firebase Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create notification simple AI for my chat application when i request form one user id to another user id it doesn't display any notification to other user id and in function there was shown the error as:

```
Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.
    at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:241:16)
    at Messaging.validateRegistrationTokensType (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:589:19)
    at Messaging.sendToDevice (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:210:14)
    at Promise.all.then.result (/user_code/index.js:92:32)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

I'm not a good coder of nodejs i referred from some tutorial from google but it doesn't work for me can any one help me why this error will be shown and how to fixed it. also i have no any notification form one to another user id.
Here is my nodejs code:
index.js:

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {

  const user_id = event.params.user_id;
  const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

  console.log('We have a notification from : ', user_id);

  if(!event.data.val()){

    return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);

  }

  const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');

  return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

    const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;

    console.log('You have new notification from  : ', from_user_id);


    const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`Users/${from_user_id}/name`).once('value');
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

    return Promise.all([userQuery, deviceToken]).then(result => {

      const userName = result[0].val();
      const token_id = result[1].val();

      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title : "New Friend Request",
          body: `${userName} has sent you request`,
          icon: "default",
          click_action : "com.rotaractnepalapp.rotraconversation_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
        },
        data : {
          from_user_id : from_user_id
        }
      };

      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

      return console.log('This was the notification Feature');

      });

    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because:

```
const userName = result[0].val();
const token_id = result[1].val();
```

one of the above is empty, you need to add `console.log()` to check which one. Also you need to check your database and path database in `ref()` to be sure that there is a token.

Comment: sir can you give example i can't understood how to check console.log() for above two const and the ref() is correct there is token sorry for bad English

Comment: i'm a beginner that's why i'm asking you sir

Comment: console.log("user is", userName); console.log("token is", token_id);

Comment: thx but when i deploy firebase i got 32:12  warning  Avoid nesting promises  promise/no-nesting
  52:14  warning  Avoid nesting promises  promise/no-nesting warning how to remove it sir

Comment: sir it's doesn't work for me :( no notification when i sent to request

Comment: did you deploy it?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rVyGcgE5J6WgSBQ4UnJzzkenMqWOCSr4/view?usp=sharing       this is my code sir

Comment: in the firebase console log , the place where you deployed it , check what the console.log gives you

Comment: this is error found again sir https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rUUo7VqvGFCwxJqEmzGT5ID8CRFDK_jr

Comment: yes as you can see in the logs token id is null and username is also null. You need to check your database

Comment: when this solution help for me i will up for ur answer sir